# Handlebars node html-to-pdf reports allow certain number of items in one page

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to print barcodes for 3 x 11 Sheet. I use HTML template using handlebars and print them to pdf.  I use pdf-creator-node library which uses html-to-pdf library inside.Some product names are long while some are short. What I need is the set the page for fix number of items. 11 rows for each page. How can I do it on my template? How can I make it so after 11 rows the report jumps the second page? It may have something to with css page-break-after but I can't figure out how to use it.

BarcodeTemplate.html

```
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Tutorial Sample Page</title>
    <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            {{#everyNth reportData 3}}
              {{#if isModZeroNotFirst}}
                </div>
              {{/if}}
              {{#if isModZero}}
                <div class="row">
              {{/if}}
              <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
                <img class="text-center" style="margin-bottom:1px;height:30px"  src="{{barcode_image}}" />
                <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:-3px;margin-bottom:1px">{{barcode}}</div>
                <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:-5px;margin-bottom:-3px;line-height: 9px">{{name}}</div>
                <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-5px">{{sku}}</div>
                <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:-5px;margin-bottom:1px">{{intax_price}}</div>
              </div>
              {{#if isLast}}
                </div>
              {{/if}}
            {{/everyNth}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('everyNth', function(context, every, options) {
      var fn = options.fn, inverse = options.inverse;
      var ret = "";
      if(context && context.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0, j=context.length; i<j; i++) {
          var modZero = i % every === 0;
          var jumpNextPage = (i!== 0 && i % 33 === 0)
          ret = ret + fn(_.extend({}, context[i], {
            isModZero: modZero && !jumpNextPage,
            isModZeroNotFirst: modZero && i > 0,
            isLast: i === context.length - 1,
            isNextPage: jumpNextPage && modZero
          }));
        }
      } else {
        ret = inverse(this);
      }
      return ret;
    });


    <div class="container">
            {{#everyNth reportData columnCount}}
                {{#if isModZeroNotFirst}}
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
                {{#if isModZero}}
                    <div class="row">
                {{/if}}
                {{#if isNextPage}}
                    <div class="row" style="page-break-after:always;" >
                {{/if}}
                <div class='{{columnClass}}'>
                    {{#if show_barcode}}
                    <img class="text-center" style="margin-bottom:0px;height:30px"  src="{{barcode_image}}" />
                    {{/if}}
                    {{#if show_barcode_number}}
                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:-3px;margin-bottom:0px">{{barcode}}</div>
                    {{/if}}
                    {{#if show_product_name}}
                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:-3px;margin-bottom:-3px;line-height: 9px">{{name}}</div>
                    {{/if}}
                    {{#if show_sku}}
                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:-5px">{{sku}}</div>
                    {{/if}}
                    {{#if show_intax_price}}
                    <div class="text-center" style="font-size:9px;margin-top:-5px;margin-bottom:1px">{{intax_price}}</div>
                    {{/if}}
                </div>
                {{#if isLast}}
                    </div>
                {{/if}}
            {{/everyNth}}
        </div>
```